# How can I clone the form ( address input) ? not working

Tags: javascript

How can I clone the form ( address input) ? not working
how to fix this problem
I want to do in such a way as when the user deletes the input and then add it, it should be an active input again. https://jsfiddle.net/joio/95o0wyfy/29

```
$('.add_input').eq(0).click(function() {
            form_a++;
            var formhtml = $('#divform_a .form').eq(0).html().toString();
            formhtml = formhtml.replace(/form_a/g, 'form_item'+form_a);
            $('#divform_a').eq(0).append('<div class="form">' + formhtml + '</div>');
                    focus_map_location = jQuery('#divform_a .form:last .map_location');

            $("#divform_a .form:last .address").removeAttr('id');
            address_form = $("#address").parent();
            $("#address").clone(true).prependTo(address_form).removeAttr('id');
            address_name = $("#divform_a .form:last .address").attr('name');
            $("#divform_a .form:last .address").remove();
            $("#address").prependTo($("#divform_a .form:last")).attr('name',address_name).val('');
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be in these two lines

```
address_form = $("#address").parent();
$("#address").clone(true).prependTo(address_form).removeAttr('id');
```

Your code does not set id to the newly created `input` tags. Once you delete the original element with the id, the prepen stops working. Also, this seems a lot more complicated than it should be.

This is all that it takes to duplicate (and also to get the name tag working)

```
$('.add_input').click(function() {
    form_a++;
    var copiedForm = $('#divform_a .form').eq(0).clone();
    copiedForm.attr('name', 'form_item'+form_a);
    $('#divform_a').append(copiedForm);
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/95o0wyfy/18/)

EDIT:

Here's your fiddle with [minimal](https://jsfiddle.net/95o0wyfy/21/) changes. The following line at the end, reinstates the `#address` to the first input and now the copy function works as it should

```
$("#divform_a .form:first .address").attr('id', 'address');
```

I would still advise to take a look at the code in the first fiddle and try to clean up. Or at the very least, learn from it :)

Second Edit:

In your map fiddle, you're initializing autocomplete only for the first field. You should do something like this

```
$('.address').each(function(){
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(this);
    autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map); 
    autocomplete.setTypes([]);
    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete,'place_changed', function() {
        infowindow.close();
        markerPoint.setVisible(false);
        var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
        if (!place.geometry) {
          return;
        }
    });
  });
  });
```

This will make an Autocomplete of both fields. The clone's automatically pick up the property.

Comment: The problem is that some of the functional part is based on this code, would not like to makes sweeping changes

Comment: I think it would be safer to clone. I guess. But if you do want to keep it like it is, then you should add one a line at the end of your click functions, to put back the id attribute

Comment: Thank you , You can show me specifically in jsfiddle , properly

Comment: I did some changes and put in an updated fiddle in my answer. Did you take a look? Let me know if you see anything wierd in it

Comment: This code is very different from my, i tried many different methods , but it's still not working
i think problem is in line (without this line, the script work well)

`$("#divform_a .form:last .address").removeAttr('id');
  address_form = $("#address").parent();`

but i need this `address id`

Comment: or problem is in `$('.minus_input').eq(0).click(function() {
  if(form_a > 1)form_a--;       
  $('#divform_a .form').eq(form_a).remove();
    });` 

`$('.minus_input2').eq(0).click(function() {
  if(form_b > 1)form_b--;       
  $('#divform_b .form').eq(form_b).remove();
    }); `

Comment: No, it definitely was in your add event listener. Let me update a line and check your fiddle

Comment: Will need to get to my pc. Will post an update in an hour

Comment: -or maybe problem is `if(form_a > 1)form_a--;` and `if(form_b > 1)form_b--;`   if i change  `if(form_a > 1)form_a--;` and `if(form_b > 1)form_b--;`  the script work well for me , but the script delete all input when i pressed minus 
https://jsfiddle.net/95o0wyfy/19/

Comment: works fine, but when I write in the input address an address, address not displayed (it is autocomplete),
(Before i making this change, the autocomplete  it  worked) , how to fix it?
Thanks

Comment: @prower I'm not sure how you have your autocomplete works, but I think you'll find it easier to use the `.clone(true)` to get all your listeners and data copied into the new element. The way you're doing it now, you're just making a copy just the html.

Comment: I did a lot of tests, and I realized, after I added this line `$("#divform_a .form:first .address").attr('id', 'address');`, if you add 3 or more entries (input), only the first two (2) entries (inputs) are working well (functionality works well(with address)),  the other inputs is a simple inputs, how can I fix it?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe you should add the autocomplete to the fiddle, so I can take a look?

Comment: I'm unable to update or share fiddles for some reason, but I made a change around your Autocomplete and it worked well for me. Updating answer

Comment: I changed it    `var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
  autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map); 
  autocomplete.setTypes([]);`
to this
  `$('.address').each(function(){
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(this);
    autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map); 
    autocomplete.setTypes([]);
  });`
strange, to me, this changes does not work

Comment: One more thing, try commenting your addDOMListener and simply call the function `initialize();` at the end of your script

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: autocomplete is not defined error in line google.maps.event.addListener(**autocomplete**, 'place_changed', function() {
`var input = (
document.getElementById('adress'));
$('.adress').each(function(){
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(this);
autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map); 
autocomplete.setTypes([]);
});
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var markerPoint = new google.maps.Marker({
map: map,
anchorPoint: new google.maps.Point(0, -29)
});
google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {`

Comment: You should move this `google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed',..` into the each loop, because you want it to be added to `$('.adress').each(function{...})` of the address bars. Like, the line right after  `autocomplete.setTypes`

Comment: Also, @prower you should update the question so that it becomes easier for both of us to track/read your problems. Following comments is getting really hard now. You can just post a note here saying you've updated question

Comment: I updated my question, please review my question, Thanks you very much

Comment: Updated answer. Your latest fiddle doesn't seem to be working, but for your error, you just need to change switch the `.addListener(autocomplete,'place_changed'` into the `.each` function

Comment: nothing has changed so far, the autocomplete on the address doesn't work, though I think that the error appears when the input is deleted, because all the form html removes. But when the page is refreshed (originally, without delete) there is an id which is responsible for that input address (autocomplete). I need to detect why and what the problem is, dilemma :)

Comment: Can you try to give as close to your problem in a fiddle? The fiddle in your answer isn't working

Comment: updated the questions
I would like to come back to the original script jsfiddle.net/joio/95o0wyfy/29, and to the line added by you $("#divform_a .form:first .address").attr('id', 'address');. In this sample, everything works well, but when I add input, it has the id="address",jsfiddle.net/95o0wyfy/21 but I don't need this added input to have this id. It will be added automatically as soon as the user click on that input, but I want to do in such a way as when the user deletes the input and then add it, it should be an active input again